# Cheapest and shortest path between two nodes

Tags: algorithm, prolog, shortest-path

I have the need to find the cheapest and shortest path between two nodes in a weighted graph with cycles. I am implementing this in Prolog.

Since I have to find the **cheapest** (most cheap) and the **shortest** (most short) path, I figured I should calculate all of the existing possible paths by using depth-first search with backtracking because of its low memory consumption and being relatively fast (I use an auxiliary list to keep track of the visited nodes to take care of the cycles problems), and then pick from the collected list of paths the cheapest and the shortest path.

I ruled out the use of algorithms with heuristics (e.g. A*) because, although faster, these rely on estimate functions and they could give wrong answers on some specific cases where the estimate might be wrong. I do not want a good solution, I want the **best** solution.

So my question is: Does the approach I have given to this problem make sense, more specifically, to assure that I am getting the most/least something (e.g. cheapest) path  in a graph problem between two nodes with cycles, does it make sense to calculate all of the existing solutions and then pick the right one by comparing it with the others or am I tackling this problem the wrong way?

Comment: Seeing as A* is based on Dijkstra's algorithm, but with heuristics to speed it up (which you don't want), why not just use Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: @JosephYoung I hadn't thought about using Dijkstra's to be honest. But it might be the better option. Still, do you think it is bad to collect all the solutions and then pick the one you want from them?

Comment: What does the cheapest and the shortest mean here? Do edges have weights? If yes, can they be negative?

Comment: @kraskevich The nodes represent cities. Cities have distances between them and a travel price. Some cities are only accessible by certain means of transportation which means travelling to them is more expensive than to other cities.

Comment: Are these two actually separate problems? Can the shortest and the cheapest paths be completely different?

Comment: @kraskevich Yes, they can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use a custom algorithm here. You can just use a standard shortest path finding algorithm (Dijkstra's if all weights are non-negative and Ford-Bellman's or Floyd's otherwise). The weights of the edges should be costs and the distances for the first and the second problem, respectively.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that I have to make two implementations of Dijkstra algorithm and run them both? One to find the cheapest path and another to find the shortest?

Comment: No this mean the cost of a path would be a pair (cost, distance). So, when comparing two paths a, and b. You take the one with the smaller cost and if they have the same cost, you take the one with the shorter distance.

Comment: But the shortest and cheapest can be two different paths, and what you're saying will only give me one.

Comment: @JoãoPaiva Yes, I mean that its necessary to build two graphs and run Dijkstra's algorithm twice.

Comment: @kraskevich Can I use Dijkstra if my graph has cycles?

Comment: @JoãoPaiva Yes. The only restrictions is that all weights must be non-negative.